# Google Maps API not showing places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been using a Google maps API v3 (Javascript) for a map, everything's been working great.

Recently we got a Google API for Work account. So, we've incorporated our client ID in our map call:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=gme-clientid&v=3.18"></script>`

And ever since then, restaurants, banks, stores, etc. do not appear on the map. Only big places, like Universities, state parks, airports, etc.

Removing the `client` parameter from the src restores the expected functionality.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, or how to restore the desired functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume either by default for when a client ID is specified, or perhaps setup specifically for your account, that those types of features are disabled.  Perhaps when you create the map if you explicitly say you want those features enabled, they should appear I would expect.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#map_features

I'm guessing these are in the `poi.business` category of features.  You could try something like:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: {lat: coordinates.latitude, lng: coordinates.longitude},
    zoom: 13,
    styles: [{
        featureType: 'poi.business',
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [{
            visibility: 'on'
        }]
    }]
});
```

If that doesn't work, try `featureType: 'all',`